# What is the minimum knowledge of CLR a .NET programmer must have to be a good programmer?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

When we talk about the .NET world the CLR is what everything we do depends on.
What is the minimum knowledge of CLR a .NET programmer must have to be a good programmer?
Can you give me one/many you think is/are the most important subjects:
GC?, AppDomain?, Threads?, Processes?, Assemblies/Fusion?

I will very much appreciate if you post a links to articles, blogs, books or other on the topic where more information could be found.

Update: I noticed from some of comments that my question was not clear to some. When I say CLR I don't mean .Net Framework. It is NOT about memorizing .NET libraries, it is rather to understand how does the execution environment (in which those libraries live on runtime) work.

My question was directly inspired by John Robbins the author of "Debugging Applications for Microsoft® .NET" book (which I recommend) and colleague of here cited Jeffrey Richter at Wintellect. In one of introductory chapters he is saying that "...any .NET programmer should know what is probing and how assemblies are loaded into runtime". Do you think there are other such things?

Last Update: After having read first 5 chapters of "CLR via C#" I must say to anyone reading this. If you haven't allready, read this book!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Most of those are way deeper than the kind of thing many developers fall down on in my experience. Most misunderstood (and important) aspects in my experience:

- Value types vs reference types
- Variables vs objects
- Pass by ref vs pass by value
- Delegates and events
- Distinguishing between language, runtime and framework
- Boxing
- Garbage collection

On the "variables vs objects" front, here are three statements about the code

```
string x = "hello";
```

- (Very bad) `x` is a string with 5 letters
- (Slightly better) `x` is a reference to a string with 5 letters
- (Correct) The value of `x` is a reference to a string with 5 letters

Obviously the first two are okay in "casual" conversation, but only if everyone involved understands the real situation.

Comment: plus Exception handling and garbage collection

Comment: Boxing? Do .Net developers really get picked on that much? :)

Comment: Exception handling is more a case of good design than fundamental understanding of what exceptions do, in my experience. But yes, I'll add GC to the list.

Comment: Boxing - yup - us microserf$ get picked on a lot

Comment: +1 for exception management, because I've been surprised how many developers don't understand how two-pass model.

Comment: I wouldn't say you need to know this stuff to be a _good_ .Net programmer. I'd say this is stuff you need to be a PASSABLE .Net programmer. Seriously, wtf?

Comment: for entry level that's a fine place to start. Even if you don't know those things a willingness and desire to learn is a bonus.

Comment: @TraumaPony: You'd be amazed at the number of people I've interviewed who don't "get" this stuff.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Bah, I hope you didn't hire any of them :P

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks for the answer, alldough I voted it up there is 1 thing I don't understand: What do you mean by "Variables vs objects"?

Comment: enba: People often talk about an "object named x" when they mean "the object that variable x's value refers to". That kind of shorthand is okay so long as it isn't due to a real misunderstanding. You need to understand that the value of a variable is never an object itself. Some people don't :(

Comment: @Jon: do you mean that variables are secretly pointers^H^H^H^H^H^H^H that "P" word ?

Comment: ok, now I see. What is the difference between "X is a reference" and "the value of X is a reference"?

Comment: or I guess, what is the distinction between "x and y are references to the same something" and "x and y have identical values, which is a reference to something"

Comment: @JonSkeet - Do you need to understand how the CLR handle these things in order to really understand them?

Comment: @Sipo: I'm not really sure what you're asking. My answer says that there are significantly higher-level, more central topics that developers fall down on. It's also worth bearing in mind that this question and answer are more than 11 years old now - that's more than half the lifetime of .NET. (And Stack Overflow itself has changed a lot - I think this question would have been closed these days.)

Comment: Well, your answers are timeless. :) Would you change your answer nowadays?

Comment: @Sipo: I probably wouldn't answer a question like this, to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

A *great* programmer cannot be measured by the quantity of things he knows about the CLR. Sure it's a nice beginning, but he must also know OOP/D/A and a lot of other things like Design Patterns, Best Practices, O/RM concepts etc.

Fact is I'd say a "great .Net programmer" doesn't necessary need to know much about the CLR at all as long as he has great knowledge about general programming theory and concepts...

I would rather hire a "great Java developer" with great general knowledge and experience in Java for a .Net job then a "master" in .Net that have little experience and thinks O/RM is a stock ticker and stored procedures are a great way to "abstract away the database"...

I've seen *professional teachers* in .Net completely fail in doing really simple things without breaking their backs due to lack of "general knowledge" while they at the same time "know everything" there is to know about .Net and the CLR...

Answer (score 4):

Updated: reading the relevant parts of the book CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter..this book can be a good reference..

Comment: I haven't even heard of that book, yet I've done plenty of work with the CLR and can tell you all about appdomains/assemblies/etc/etc. Am I somehow less qualified for not having read a particluar single book?

Comment: i did not mean that way. i read it pretty late too. just that it is a good consolidated place for lots of clr related stuff. will edit my post.

Comment: agreed.. different people have different paths to attain knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Should know about Memory Management, Delegates

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer seems to be pretty complete to me (plus delegates) but I think what fundamentally seperates a good programmer from an average one is answering the why questions rather than the how.  It's great to know how garbage collections works and how value types and reference types work, but it's a whole other level to understand when to use a value type vs. reference type.  It's the difference between speaking in a language vs. giving a speech in a language (it's all about how we apply the knowledge we have and how we arrive at those decisions).

Comment: Knowing why is important, but until you understand how a thing works you can't reliably answer why you should (or shouldn't) use it under given conditions.

Comment: Agreed...  I was just commenting that how something is done vs. the why really seperates the difference between an average developer and a great developer

Answer (score 0):

Jon's answer is good. Those are all fairly basic but important areas that a lot of developers do not have a good understanding of. I think knowing the difference between value and reference types ties in to a basic understanding of how the GC in .NET behaves, but, more importantly, a good understanding of the Dispose pattern is important.

The rest of the areas you mention are either very deep knowledge about the CLR itself or more advanced concepts that aren't widely used (yet). [.NET 4.0 will start to change some of that with the introduction of the parallel extensions and MEF.]

Comment: Agree that understanding IDisposable is important. No upvote though because its a framework and language concept. The CLR knows nothing about it..

Comment: The CLR absolutely knows about IDisposable since it is integral to the memory management processing done by the CLR.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can be really tricky to grasp is deferred execution and the likes.

How do you explain how a method that returns an IEnumerable works? What does a delegate really do? things like that.